# trouble connecting to steam servers

Tags: steam

I log in to my steam account with internet, without coming up with an option of offline mode it goes straight to steam warning, steam is having trouble connecting to the steam servers, does not fix when I restart computer or try authenticating or updating my account. Could anyone please explain to me what's happening?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to steam through your browser?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You may experience connection issues to the Steam servers around the morning time in America. If you live in Europe this will pose an issue. Furthermore, Valve will occasionally do server maintenance however they usually last between 10 - 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all files except Steam.exe and steamapps folder.
I faced this issue yesterday and it solved my problem.